# PROLOG- occurrences of subsequence into a number

Tags: prolog

> Using Prolog language, I need to find out the number of occurrences of a sub-sequence in a number.

I tried to count occurrences of a word in a big text file and it didn't work out either. Though I have the code from it.

```
word_freq(W, Freq) :-
    word_count(W, 0, Total, 0, Match),
    Total > 0 -> Freq is Match / Total.

word_count(W, TotSoFar, Tot, MatchSoFar, Match) :-
    (  read_word(SoFar,W),
    N \= end_of_file
    -> T1 is TotSoFar + 1,
    (  N == W
    -> M1 is MatchSoFar+1
    ;  M1 is MatchSoFar
    ),
    word_count(W, T1, Tot, M1, Match)
    ; TotSoFar = Tot,
    MatchSoFar = Match
    ).

read_word(SoFar, W) :-
    get_code(C),
    (   C == -1
    ->  ( SoFar == [] -> W = end_of_file ; reverse(SoFar, W) )
    ;   code_type(C, alnum)
    ->  read_word([C|SoFar], W)
    ;   reverse(SoFar, W)
    ).
```

I suppose the occurrence/frequency count should work the same for both, or similar. I have no idea where to start or how to go on, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know what you think of this solution. I assumed that the sub-sequence must also be a number, since we are looking for its occurrences in a number.

The idea is following :

Given a Number and another number (Subsequence), subtract the Subsequence from the Number, and see whether the least significant digits are zeros (the number of least significant digits is determined by the size of the Subsequence). If they are zeros then we have subsequence , otherwise we don't. Continue to do this with the rest of the number obtained with NumberNew = Number div 10,until you get to a situation where the Number is lesser than the Subsequence.   If you have any trouble understanding the code, I'll edit the post and update it with comments.

```
subsequence_size(Subsequence,1) :- Subsequence < 10,!.
subsequence_size(Subsequence,Size) :- SubNew is Subsequence div 10,subsequence_size(SubNew,N),Size is N+1. 


is_subsequence(_,0).
is_subsequence(Number,SubSize) :-  Rem is Number mod 10,
                                   Rem=0,
                                   NumberNew is Number div 10,
                                   SubSizeNew is SubSize - 1,
                                   is_subsequence(NumberNew,SubSizeNew).

occurence_of_subsequence_in_number(Subsequence,Number,Occurences) :- subsequence_size(Subsequence,SubSize),
                                                                     count(Subsequence,SubSize,Number,0,Occurences).

count(0,_,0,Occurences,1) :- Occurences=0,!.
count(0,_,0,Occurences,Occurences) :- not(Occurences=0),!.
count(Subsequence,_,Number,Occurences,Occurences) :- Subsequence > Number,!.
count(Subsequence,SubSize,Number,Occurences,FinalOccurences) :- NumberToTest is Number-Subsequence,
                                                                (is_subsequence(NumberToTest,SubSize)),
                                                                OccurencesNew is Occurences+1,
                                                                NumberNew is Number div 10,
                                                                count(Subsequence,SubSize,NumberNew,OccurencesNew,FinalOccurences),!.

count(Subsequence,SubSize,Number,Occurences,FinalOccurences) :- NumberToTest is Number-Subsequence,
                                                                not(is_subsequence(NumberToTest,SubSize)),
                                                                NumberNew is Number div 10,
                                                                count(Subsequence,SubSize,NumberNew,Occurences,FinalOccurences),!.
```